# UITableView not updating data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, reloaddata

I have trying for sometime to make the "`reloadData()`" work but it is not working. I've even tried "`DispatchQueue.main.async{self.tableView.reloadData()}`"

Below is the code

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import GameKit

enum Tags: Int {
    case levelLabel     = 100
    case background     = 101
    case highScoreLabel = 102
    case star1          = 201
    case star2          = 202
    case star3          = 203
}

let LightBlue   = UIColor.systemBlue
let Green       = UIColor.systemRed
let Purple      = UIColor.systemPurple
let Pink        = UIColor.systemPink
let Orange      = UIColor.systemOrange
let OneStarScore    =  5  
let TwoStarScore    = 10
let ThreeStarScore  = 15

let NumLevels = 11

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,
                            UITableViewDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var highScores: [Int] = [Int]()
    var unlockedLevels = 0
    let colors = [LightBlue, Green, Purple, Pink, Orange]

    var tutorialPageVC: PageDataSourceViewController?
    var gameVC: GameViewController?



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        let storyboard = self.storyboard

        tutorialPageVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageDataSourceVC")
            as? PageDataSourceViewController

        gameVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController")
            as? GameViewController

        // Trying to fix UITableView
        /// Put code here
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(false)

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if let scoresArray = defaults.array(forKey: "highScores") {

            highScores = scoresArray as! [Int]

            unlockedLevels = highScores.count - 1 // Subtract one for tutorial

            if highScores[unlockedLevels] >= 5 {
                unlockedLevels += 1 // Unlock additional level if last high score is greater than 5

            }
        }




    }

// MARK: - TableView data source methods

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return NumLevels
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LevelCell", for: indexPath) 

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

        let view = cell.viewWithTag(Tags.background.rawValue) as UIView?
        let levelLabel = cell.viewWithTag(Tags.levelLabel.rawValue) as! UILabel
        let scoreLabel = cell.viewWithTag(Tags.highScoreLabel.rawValue) as! UILabel

        let star1 = cell.viewWithTag(Tags.star1.rawValue) as! UIImageView
        let star2 = cell.viewWithTag(Tags.star2.rawValue) as! UIImageView
        let star3 = cell.viewWithTag(Tags.star3.rawValue) as! UIImageView

        view?.layer.borderColor = colors[indexPath.row % 5].cgColor
        view?.layer.borderWidth = 6.0


        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            // Tutorial Level

            view?.alpha = 1.0
            levelLabel.text = "Tutorial"

            star1.isHidden = true
            star2.isHidden = true
            star3.isHidden = true

            scoreLabel.text = ""

        } else if indexPath.row + 1 <= highScores.count {

            // Levels that have been played

            view?.alpha = 1.0
            levelLabel.text = "Level \(indexPath.row)"

            star1.isHidden = false
            star2.isHidden = false
            star3.isHidden = false

            formatStars(highScores[indexPath.row], stars: [star1, star2, star3])

            scoreLabel.text = "High Score: \(highScores[indexPath.row])"
        } else {

            // Levels that have NOT been played

            view?.alpha = indexPath.row > unlockedLevels ? 0.5 : 1.0

            levelLabel.text = "Level \(indexPath.row)"

            star1.isHidden = true
            star2.isHidden = true
            star3.isHidden = true

            scoreLabel.text = ""

        }

        return cell
    }

    /// Display stars for each level on homepage
    func formatStars(_ score: Int, stars: [UIImageView]) {

        switch score {

        case 0..<OneStarScore:
            stars[0].image = UIImage(named: "star-empty")
            stars[1].image = UIImage(named: "star-empty")
            stars[2].image = UIImage(named: "star-empty")

        case OneStarScore..<TwoStarScore:
            stars[0].image = UIImage(named: "star")
            stars[1].image = UIImage(named: "star-empty")
            stars[2].image = UIImage(named: "star-empty")

        case TwoStarScore..<ThreeStarScore:
            stars[0].image = UIImage(named: "star")
            stars[1].image = UIImage(named: "star")
            stars[2].image = UIImage(named: "star-empty")

        default:
            stars[0].image = UIImage(named: "star")
            stars[1].image = UIImage(named: "star")
            stars[2].image = UIImage(named: "star")
        }

    }

// MARK: - TableView delegate methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            self.present(tutorialPageVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if indexPath.row <= unlockedLevels {

            gameVC!.level = indexPath.row
            self.present(gameVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            // performSegueWithIdentifier("LevelSegue", sender: self)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate and data source of the table view to the HomeViewController?

Comment: How do you propose I do that? I am fairly new to UITableView so can you guide me?

Comment: OK, I'll write an answer to guide you.

Comment: where are you changing the values ?

Comment: In another viewcontroller

Comment: I have set the delegate and data source to the HomeViewContoller

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the connection between the `UITableView` and the delegate and data source are not set.
You could do this in the storyboard by ctrl+dragging from the table view to the view controller and setting the `delegate` and `data source` outlets.

Or you can do so in code, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: The tableview is still not updating

Comment: The connections are set

Comment: So what exactly "is not working"? Is `tableView(_:cellForRowAt)` being called? Is `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection)` being called? Set a breakpoint if unsure.

Comment: Both of them are getting called

Comment: Then it seems like your cells are not working. Try to use default cells `let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "id")` first, and only set the title, to check if this works

Comment: I just found out that it is working on iOS 12 but not on 13.

Comment: I found another thing. When you force quit the app and launch again the table is reloaded

Comment: Please try to call `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Still not updating

Answer (score 0):

You need to set dataSource and delegate to self

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
         tableView.datasource = self
}
```

And Assign values directly like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LevelCell", for: indexPath) as? LevelCell

          cell?.star1.isHidden = true
}
```